# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null for ImageButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagebutton, imageurl

I've searched through similar questions but I didn't find something to work for me.

I want to change the ImageURL of an ImageButton on a certain condition (t>80), but what I get is *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null*. My `<head>` code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
           //doing other stuffs
        setInterval(function () {

                         $(".industrial.tank.size.one").each(function () {
                            $(this).industrial(t);

                            if (t > 80) {

                                // document.getElementById('btnV11').ImageURL = "~/Images/Valve/Valve-gray-left.png";
                                document.getElementById('btnV11').src = "../../Images/Valve/Valve-gray-left.png";           
                        });  
        }, 3000);
    });
```

and in `<body>`:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnV11" runat="server" Height="51px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Valve/Valve-alarm-left.gif" Width="53px" OnClientClick="ShowControlPanel_P11(); return false;"/>
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: If ImageButton is placed in content page then id not found by DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id would be different than what you set in server side code. replace `btnV11` with `<%= btnV11.ClientID %>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           //doing other stuffs
        setInterval(function () {

                         $(".industrial.tank.size.one").each(function () {
                            $(this).industrial(t);

                            if (t > 80) {

                                // document.getElementById('btnV11').ImageURL = "~/Images/Valve/Valve-gray-left.png";
                                document.getElementById('<%= btnV11.ClientID %>').src = "../../Images/Valve/Valve-gray-left.png";           
                        });  
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: Worked as you suggested. Thank you!